# deleting duplicates taking days on bloated table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database that I've messed up by adding too many duplicates. It now has 30m rows.  My plan of attack is to drop duplicate rows as follows:

```sql
SET SESSION wait_timeout=999999; -- to avoid timeout
DELETE t1 FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
WHERE
t1.id < t2.id AND 
t1.unique_col = t2.unique_col;
```

Where `unique_col` contains some string that should be unique to each row, hence identifying duplicates.

It's been running for about 24 hours.  I know there's a lot of rows (it looks like the table takes 24 gb of memory, not great either) so high latency operations are to be expected.  Is this the most optimal way out of this mess?

edit: my show tables with obfuscated column names:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `...` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `...` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `...` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `...` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `...` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `...` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unique_col` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `...` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `...` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `...` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
```

Comment: show output of `show create table yourtablename`

Comment: I would prefer to delete by chunks, meaning delete let's say 10.000 rows, wait some seconds, delete next 10.000 etc. So I would add something like "ORDER BY t1.id LIMIT 10000" to your delete command. Put that command in a script and add a sleep of some seconds between the executions.

Comment: another way is to create a new table without duplicates, swap them, drop the old one.

Comment: JHH, that sounds like a simple solution, however I'm not sure how I'd formulate such a create statement.